# Can I close a Windows Form from a link in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Okay, I have a WebBrowser control in my VB.NET application that loads a PHP page inside it. On the PHP page I have a 'Log Out' hyperlink. What I'm trying to do is close the VB.NET form when that hyperlink is clicked. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this - assuming it's even possible?

Comment: (copied from an old link-only answer) **Interacting with the Web Browser Control**
http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/27/1334.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured this one out. I just had the browser control check the URL after it loaded the login page and forced it to close the form that way.